# Extract multiple dataframes from dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, scikit-learn

I'm doing some single cell RNA-sequencing using scprep. I'm using the command 
        `scprep.stats.differential_expression_by_cluster(data, clusters)` where clusters is an output from sk.learn kmeans.

According to the docs, the output is dict(pd.DataFrame).

My output looks like this:

```
 {0:                               difference   rank
 C1qb (ENSMUSG00000036905)       0.176254      0
 C1qa (ENSMUSG00000036887)       0.145618      1
 C1qc (ENSMUSG00000036896)       0.120607      2
 Crybb1 (ENSMUSG00000029343)     0.105344      3
 Tyrobp (ENSMUSG00000030579)     0.098916      4
 ...                                  ...    ...
 mt-Co3 (ENSMUSG00000064358)   -68.884323  16091
 Malat1 (ENSMUSG00000092341)   -77.371274  16092
 Tuba1a (ENSMUSG00000072235)   -91.835869  16093
 Tmsb4x (ENSMUSG00000049775)  -101.908864  16094
 mt-Atp6 (ENSMUSG00000064357) -120.025289  16095

 [16096 rows x 2 columns], 1:                               difference   rank
 Tmsb4x (ENSMUSG00000049775)   127.537848      0
 Tuba1a (ENSMUSG00000072235)    91.644383      1
 Tubb2b (ENSMUSG00000045136)    48.972048      2
 mt-Atp6 (ENSMUSG00000064357)   41.105186      3
 Stmn1 (ENSMUSG00000028832)     40.466334      4
 ...                                  ...    ...
 Meg3 (ENSMUSG00000021268)      -2.904875  16091
 Hmgb2 (ENSMUSG00000054717)     -4.784257  16092
 Vim (ENSMUSG00000026728)       -5.001676  16093
 Dbi (ENSMUSG00000026385)       -6.704505  16094
 Fabp7 (ENSMUSG00000019874)    -12.319859  16095

 [16096 rows x 2 columns], 2:                              difference   rank
 Gria2 (ENSMUSG00000033981)     1.688701      0
 Pou3f2 (ENSMUSG00000095139)    1.167767      1
 Pou3f3 (ENSMUSG00000045515)    0.999804      2
 Cldn5 (ENSMUSG00000041378)     0.971778      3
 Robo2 (ENSMUSG00000052516)     0.877576      4
```

When I try `pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict)` I get an error message

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-383-630287ba17f3> in <module>
----> 1 df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(diff)

~/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in from_dict(cls, data, orient, dtype, columns)
   1188             raise ValueError("only recognize index or columns for orient")
   1189 
-> 1190         return cls(data, index=index, columns=columns, dtype=dtype)
   1191 
   1192     def to_numpy(self, dtype=None, copy=False):

~/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in __init__(self, data, index, columns, dtype, copy)
    409             )
    410         elif isinstance(data, dict):
--> 411             mgr = init_dict(data, index, columns, dtype=dtype)
    412         elif isinstance(data, ma.MaskedArray):
    413             import numpy.ma.mrecords as mrecords

~/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/construction.py in init_dict(data, index, columns, dtype)
    255             arr if not is_datetime64tz_dtype(arr) else arr.copy() for arr in arrays
    256         ]
--> 257     return arrays_to_mgr(arrays, data_names, index, columns, dtype=dtype)
    258 
    259 

~/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/construction.py in arrays_to_mgr(arrays, arr_names, index, columns, dtype)
     75     # figure out the index, if necessary
     76     if index is None:
---> 77         index = extract_index(arrays)
     78     else:
     79         index = ensure_index(index)

~/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/construction.py in extract_index(data)
    356 
    357         if not indexes and not raw_lengths:
--> 358             raise ValueError("If using all scalar values, you must pass an index")
    359 
    360         if have_series:

ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index
```

I've tried various methods such as `pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict, orient='index')` , which gives me the following output

```
                                                   0
0                                 difference   ran...
1                                 difference   ran...
2                                difference   rank...
3                                difference   rank...
4                                 difference   ran...
5                                 difference   ran...
6                                 difference   ran...
7                                difference   rank...
8                                 difference   ran...
9                                 difference   ran...
10                                difference   ran...
11                                difference   ran...
12                                difference   ran...
13                                difference   ran...
14                                difference   ran...
15                                difference   ran...
16                                difference   ran...
17                                difference   ran...
18                               difference   rank...
19                               difference   rank...
20                                difference   ran...
21                                difference   ran...
22                               difference   rank...
23                               difference   rank...
24                               difference   rank...
25                                difference   ran...
```

I want to have 26 different csv files that have gene names as rows and 'difference' and 'rank' as columns.

I looked into the original code on github and found that the result is written as so:

```
result = {cluster : differential_expression(
        select.select_rows(data, idx=clusters==cluster),
        select.select_rows(data, idx=clusters!=cluster),
        measure = measure, direction = direction,
        gene_names = gene_names, n_jobs = n_jobs)
              for cluster in np.unique(clusters)}
```

How can I get the output I would like?

Thanks

Comment: Do you simply want to write each DataFrame in the dictionary to its own CSV file? Why is the title just about extracting DataFrames from a dictionary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you can do to retrieve the dataframes from the dictionary and save them as excel files:

```py
for key,dataframe in output.items():
    # output_dict is the dictionary of Pandas dataframes    
    dataframe.to_excel('{0}.csv'.format(key)
```

Comment: I will appreciate it if you upvote the comment. Thanks

Comment: Why are you zipping the keys and values? Isn’t `.items()` made for that?

Comment: Thanks @AMC. It is funny how we easily forget the little things.